# Inkscape Group Selection (Ctrl + G) doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

To select the elements of a group one should use Ctrl+G (Inkscape manual), but this does not work. I use an AZERTY-keybord (French style) and assume this might be the origin of the problem and require an adapted key-combination.
My problem : what is the combination of AZERTY-keys for an Inkscape Group-selection?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the keyboard issue is probably irrelevant. The Ctrl+G combination has an alternative (Shift+Ctrl+U) and this works fine. 
See https://inkscape.org/doc/keys092.html for an inventory of functions/operations and their key-combination(s).